# Creating bulk items with AzureBoard RESTAPI

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-boards

I am creating an integration with my application using python to Azure Board. I have completed the APIs till creating a single issue. Is it possible to create multiple pr bulk issues ? I do not find any link in the documentation or in in general information.

Is there a RestAPI to create bulk issues in Azure board like we have for jira?

Comment: Hi, what about using powershell to run the rest api to batch create work item?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0 If it's not what you want, what do you mean by "create multiple pr bulk issues" ? Do you mean create Pull requests? Or link work items to one pr?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It was a typo mistake, what i meant was creating multiple or bulk items in a single call. Like we do for Jira.. on a single click i want this API to create multiple items for me.

Comment: Try the above powershell task in ADO pipelines and you only need to change the number after le to get different number of work items. Is it what you want? If not, please kindly tell. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please see whether the following steps could do some help.
I run the rest api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0 in Azure devops services-pipeline. This is the code:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $connectionToken="$(PAT)" #please add the PAT as variable in your pipeline
      $base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
      
      $url= 'https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/wit/workitems/$workitemtype?api-version=6.0'
      for($i=1; $i -le 100 ; $i++) {
      Write-Host $i
    
      $body=@"
       [
          {
            "op": "add",
            "path": "/fields/System.Title",
            "value": "TestCreateWI"
          }
       ]
      "@
      Write-Host "$url"
      $response= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url  -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Body $body -headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method POST
      }
```

And after it finishes, you will see these work items in your boards:
[image]